# Struggle to create (working) Access Form with a lot of data

Tags: forms, ms-access

The Access database & calculation tool I am making basically takes in a few order numbers, adds a lot of engineering calculations, and is supposed to put it all into a PDF printable form.

I figure I just make a form and later see how to best get that printable.

Overview:

- 1 Table "Calculation Reports" holds the input and output data
- Each "Calculation Report" row holds between 1 and 2 "Engines", only the order numbers of the selected engine are stored in this record. (In columns: "Engine 1", and "Engine 2")
- Each "Calculation Report" row also holds between 1 and 4 "Wheels", likewise only order numbers are stored (columns "Engine 1: Wheel 1", "Engine 1: Wheel 2", "Engine 2: Wheel 1", "Engine 2: Wheel 2")
- There is a table with all "Engines", and a table with all "Wheels"
- I have defined the relationships between the "Calculation Reports" fields and the other tables.
- In the form a lot of data from these other tables from the selected engines and wheels must be shown.
- I tried to make Queries (1 for engine 1, 1 for engine 2, 1 each for each wheel), and create a form (using form wizard) to complete all this data. But the form never loads / shows anything.

In summary: 
My form is primarily loaded from "Calculation Report", I want to also show a lot of other data from other tables based on order numbers in the primary. How do I do this?

I have tried Googling but also don't find clear advice on how to do this. I have no idea anymore on how to proceed.

Comment: Build a report instead of form for print. Build query that joins tables to use as report RecordSource. Your table design appears to not be normalized and is likely cause of frustration. Likely have to include Engines and Wheels tables in query multiple times. Your question is about design, not programming and therefore not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: I need to print a report on only one record, report seems to do many always. With more normalization you mean have a table with "Drivetrains" combining 1 Engine with 2 Wheels, and then have the "Calculations Report" have a multiple values field for "Drivetrains". Lastly the question is about getting something to work, if it is due to design then the design currently causes a critical error..

Comment: I never recommend using multi-value fields.